# how to cat a part of log in linux?

Tags: regex, logging, cat

My log format:

> 2016-02-05 23:42:57,077 INFO  dao.MoHisDao (MoHisDao.java:insertMoHisProcessed(51)) - Insert MO_HIS after processed: MoMessage[msisdn=841634683182, shortCode=null, content=TNMC, receiveTime=2016-02-05 23:42:55.0]. Time taken: 4ms.

How to get info from log in the format `841634683182|TNMC|2016-02-05 23:42:55`?

Comment: Have you tried sed command to extract those fields with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try perl one liner

```
perl -ne '
($msid,$content,$time )= m/\[msisdn\=(\d+).+?content=(\w+),\sreceiveTime=(.+?)\]/;
 print "$msid|$content|$time\n"; 
' log.txt
```

Comment: Nice answer...  but I think you need a `\n` at the end of your print if there are multiple records returned

Comment: @Hambone Thank your for your useful comment. Post edited :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with Perl as a solution, this would do the trick:

```
use strict;

open my $IN, 'test.log' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
  my ($id, $content, $time) =
    /\[msisdn=(\d+),.*content=([^,]+), receiveTime=([^\]]+)\]/;
  print join ('|', $id, $content, $time), "\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Bear in mind, I took some liberties with your formats.  I assumed:

1. your msisdn id is always numeric
2. the other two values never contain a closing square bracket ']'

If any of these assumptions are off, or is there is a way to better refine them (ie content is always alphanumeric), then it can be improved upon.

Output result:

```
841634683182|TNMC|2016-02-05 23:42:55.0
```